# MySQL Query in PHP - How to display vertical results in a horizontal table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have inherited a table that holds data collected from a webform, but stacks all the responses into one column like below - there are a lot more rows than this but this is an example,

```
U_ID    Q_ID  textResponse
1       1     jon
1       2     toomey    
1       3     some@email.com
1       4     NULL
1       5     NULL
2       1     bob
2       2     smith
2       3     another@email.com
2       4     NULL
2       5     NULL
3       1     jim
3       2     kirk
3       3     captains@log.com
3       4     NULL
3       5     NULL
```

I need to seperate all the responses for each person into rows and ignore the NULL entries.

I want it to look like this,

```
Name     Surname    Email
jon      toomey     some@email.com
bob      smith      another@email.com
jim      kirk       captains@log.com
```

The SQL I've been trying looks like this,

```
$sql = "
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN q_id = 1 THEN textResponse 
    END AS Name
FROM Responses 
UNION
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN q_id = 2 THEN textResponse 
        END AS Surname
    FROM Responses 
UNION
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN q_id = 3 THEN textResponse 
        END AS Email
    FROM Responses
";
```

The PHP I've written looks like this,

```
<?php while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row)
            echo "<td>" . $row . "</td>"; 
            ?>
    </tr>
 <?php
     } 
 ?>
```

but it's just giving me everything in one line, rather than three columns

MySQL  5.7.18
PHP 5.3.3

Any ideas?

Cheers
Jon

Comment: Please show us your expected output, and also include any query you may have tried.

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: `WHERE textResponse IS NOT NULL` in your SQL query will get rid of the NULLs. As for the rest, it would help to show us the code which currently displays this data to the user, and also for you to provide some representation of exactly how you'd like it to look instead. And if you've made any attempt to solve it so far, please show us that too - on this site we tend to help with specific, well-defined code problems, or questions about code concepts. We don't generally provide code for entire features or changes just from nothing, especially ones with vague or ambiguous requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to do this in your php code:

First get everything by

```
SELECT `Q_ID`, `textResponse` FROM `Responses` ORDER BY `U_ID`, `Q_ID`
```

Then in your while do something like this

```
$table_rows = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  switch($row['Q_ID']) {
    case '1': 
      $table_rows .= '<tr><td>' . $row['textResponse'] . '</td>';
      break;
    case '2':
    case '3':
      $table_rows .= '<td>' . $row['textResponse'] . '</td>';
      break;
    case '4':
      $table_rows .= '</tr>';
      break;
  }
}
```

Lastly, wrap it in proper table markup and send it back:

```
die('<table><tbody>' . $table_rows . '</tbody></table>');
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't even considered doing this in the php, I was so focused on the SQL query